# Red5 recording file duration

Tags: java, red5

I am using red5 1.0.6

This is my code to save a stream.

```
@Override public void streamPublishStart(IBroadcastStream stream) {
    stream.saveAs("audio/"+username+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis(), true);
    insertInDB(System.currentTimeMillis()+"", "start", "audio", username, users.get(username).room, stream.getSaveFilename());
    super.streamPublishStart(stream);
}
```

Sometimes the duration of the file is different from the stopTime - startTime. A stream was published for 12 minutes, but the file was around 45 minutes. In the file first 9 minutes was good then 9th minute to 42nd minute the file was empty(no audio) then from 42nd minute contains the audio from 9th minute of the stream.

Most of the times stream duration is not equal to saved file duration. Why does this occur?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it occurs if the broadcaster does not have enough bandwidth or processing power to publish the stream to the server; that is the primary reason in most cases. It could also be a bug in the client or server, but plenty of users record streams daily.

Comment: Is broadcast stream and publish stream different? What if I save stream using broadcast stream? Will I get the same issue?

Comment: In the server, they are the same, a ClientBroadcastStream instance.